# Kubernetes deployment database connection error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, dockerfile, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to deploy GLPI application (http://glpi-project.org/) over my Kubernetes cluster but i encounter an issue.

Here is my deployment code:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-glpi
  labels:
    type: openebs
spec:
  storageClassName: openebs-storageclass
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: glpi
  namespace: jb
  labels:
    app: glpi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: glpi
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 1 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      # unlike pod-nginx.yaml, the name is not included in the meta data as a unique name is
      # generated from the deployment name
      labels:
        app: glpi
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: pv-storage-glpi
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pv-claim-glpi
      containers:
      - name: mariadb
        image: mariadb
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "glpi"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: "glpi"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: "glpi"
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: "glpi"
        - name: GLPI_SOURCE_URL
          value: "https://forge.glpi-project.org/attachments/download/2020/glpi-0.85.4.tar.gz"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mariadb
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mariadb/
          name: pv-storage-glpi
          subPath: mariadb
      - name: glpi
        image: driket54/glpi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        - containerPort: 8090
          name: https
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/glpidata
          name: pv-storage-glpi
          subPath: glpidata
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glpi
  namespace: jb
spec:
  selector:
    app: glpi
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    name: http
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 8090
    targetPort: https
    name: https
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: mariadb
    name: mariadb
  type: NodePort  
---
```

The docker image is properly deployed but in my test phase, during the setup of the app, i get the following error while setting up the database (mysql).

[image: error glpi]

I've already checked the credentials (host, username, password) and the are correct

Please help

Comment: Do you get anything from the kubernetes pod logs? Are you able to connect to the database using a tool like toad?

Comment: What are you giving as host to the database? According to your manifest you could use localhost since containers are in same pod. Did you try to connect to database or exec into database container to verify it is up and running? Can you give us output of `kubectl get pods -n jb`?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer since I don' t have the Kubernetes knowledge expected, but I can't add a comment yet :(

What you should alter first is your GLPi version.
Use this link. It's the last one:
https://github.com/glpi-project/glpi/releases/download/9.3.0/glpi-9.3.tgz

Then you may use cli tools to  setup the database.
https://glpi-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line.html

Using what I get from your file:

```
php scripts/cliinstall.php --host=mariadb(not sure about this one in your environment but you get hte idea) --db=glpi --user=glpi --pass=glpi
```